# How does cancellation work for IAsyncEnumerable.ToArrayAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, cancellation-token, iasyncenumerable, ix.net

I working with AsyncEnumerables to read a bunch of files into my C# application (.NET 6) and want to add an option to cancel reading. However I'm confused by the behaviour of `ToArrayAsync` when provided with a `cancellationToken`.

I tried to break it down to this snippet:

```cs
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .ToAsyncEnumerable()
    .SelectAwait(async x => { await Task.Delay(1000); return x; });

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var resultTask = enumerable.ToArrayAsync(cts.Token);

cts.Cancel();
var z = await resultTask;
```

From my understanding `SelectAwait` and `ToArrayAsync` should evaluate one entry after another (which is supported by timing it). I'd expect `ToArrayAsync` to check the provided token after everyone of those steps. I tried looking up the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/85f1eb7c53e27cccdbeee3e0b044916168843fcc/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncEnumerator.WithCancellation.cs#L20) for it and think it boils down to this bit, seemingly also supporting my assumption:

```cs
public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
{
    _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return _source.MoveNextAsync(); // REVIEW: Signal cancellation through task or synchronously?
}
```

However in practice `ToArrayAsync` fully evaluates all entries of the enumerable (taking the full 10 seconds) and returns without a cancellation-exception. Calling `ToArrayAsync` with an already cancelled token immediately throws, so presumably it only checks at the very start of its execution?

I know I can work around that by using `SelectAwaitWithCancellation` and checking to token inside its lambda, but I'm unsure about my understanding of `ToArrayAsync` and AsyncEnumerables in general, so I'd be happy about clarification about how it works and what's the design thinking behind it.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior stems from how the [`ToAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/85f1eb7c53e27cccdbeee3e0b044916168843fcc/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncIterator.cs) operator is implemented in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package. This operator checks the `CancellationToken` passed to the `GetAsyncEnumerator` method only once. It's not rechecked in each `MoveNextAsync` operation. Here is a minimal demonstration of this behavior:

```
using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
IAsyncEnumerable<int> sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToAsyncEnumerable();
IAsyncEnumerator<int> enumerator = sequence.GetAsyncEnumerator(cts.Token);
cts.Cancel();
bool moved = await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"moved: {moved}");
```

Output:

```
moved: True
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C4wWLA).

In case you want a `ToAsyncEnumerable` operator that observes properly the cancellation token, here is one:

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable2<T>(
#pragma warning restore 1998
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    using IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) break;
        yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this not actually fixed with [#1158](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/pull/1158)?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede AFAICS [that](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/pull/1158 "Cancel in-flight TaskCompletionSources in ToAsyncEnumerable(Observable).") pull request was a fix for something related with the `IObservable<T>` to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` conversion. In this question the OP is dealing with a different conversion.